# Why 20 gets printed when we run the following code snippet in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why does `20` get printed when we run the following code snippet in python shell?

```
print 0xA + 0xa
```

Comment: You're adding 10 and 10. What other result would you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 0x prefix is used to notate hexadecimal numbers. 0xA + 0xA is equal to 0x14. Print will convert this to a decimal number, which is notated as 20.

Comment: Technically [`int_to_decimal_string()`](https://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.9/file/753a8f457ddc/Objects/intobject.c#l1172) (in CPython) is what converts it, not `print`.

Answer (score 1):

`0xA` and `0xa` are [both hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) representation of the number `10`.